# How do you reference the size of an arr_arr_integer matrix?

Tags: c

I am trying to reference a matrix defined as a function parameter `arr_arr_integer` matrix.

Above the code reads this:

```
// Arrays are already defined with this interface:
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
```

I'm confused by this. Can someone help me define an `int columns` and `int rows`? I think `int rows = matrix.size;` but I'm not sure about columns.

Edit: Thanks to @paulR:

```
int rows = matrix.size;
int cols = matrix.arr->size;
```

Comment: `int cols = matrix.arr->size;`

Comment: @PaulR This is C by the way, I assume that is for C++?

Comment: No, this is just plain old C syntax.

Comment: @PaulR Wow that's pretty embarrassing, sorry haha. I was getting compilation errors but it's probably something with the website (CodeSignal). Thanks for your time though!

Comment: @PaulR you are right. I'm not sure what went wrong but it's working now, thanks for the help.